# Using CameraX in Android, but it shows only black screen. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, camera

I'm trying to get some picture using CameraX, but it won't work. Only black screen on a photo + button. There's no preview from the camera.
My android version of the phone is 11. Can anyone help with this?
I found some examples of the code, it used 'android-extensions', but now it's deprecated
and i changed some code.

I guess problem here, but i don't understand how to fix it:

it.setSurfaceProvider(Preview.SurfaceProvider { pv_camera })

That's a whole code of MainActivity:

`
package com.example.testcamerax

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.util.concurrent.Executor
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
private lateinit  var pv_camera: View

companion object {
private const val TAG = "CameraX"
private const val FILE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
private const val PERMISSION_CODE = 10
private val PERMISSION = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
}

private fun allPermissionGranted() = PERMISSION.all {
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

if (allPermissionGranted()) {
startCamera()
} else {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSION, PERMISSION_CODE)
}

cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy()
cameraExecutor.shutdown()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
requestCode: Int,
permissions: Array<out String>,
grantResults: IntArray
) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
if (allPermissionGranted()) {
startCamera()
}
else {
Toast.makeText(this, "Permission error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
finish()
}
}
}

private fun startCamera() {

val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
pv_camera = findViewById(R.id.pv_camera)
val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
.also {
it.setSurfaceProvider(Preview.SurfaceProvider { pv_camera })
}
val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

try {
cameraProvider.unbindAll()
cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
this,cameraSelector,
preview
)
} catch (e: Exception) {
Log.e(TAG, "Bind error")
}

}, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}
}
```

`

Here is XML

`

```
<FrameLayout

android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/pv_camera"/>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/btn_save"
android:text="Save"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
android:layout_margin="120dp"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

`

Thanks for reading this question. I'll be glad if anyone help.

I made a new variable pv_view, but it won't work.
First code was  `it.setSurfaceProvider(pv_camera.surfaceProvider)`
but there is problem with deprecated plugins.

Answer (score 0):

1-change pv_camera type to PreviewView

```
private lateinit var pv_camera: PreviewView
```

2- place this code in your startCamera function

```
    val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
    val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        .build()

    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(pv_camera.surfaceProvider)
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            this,
            cameraSelector,
            preview,
        )

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
```